# How do I prevent multiple Ionic React Modals from opening/closing at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

So I am building an application using Ionic + React. I am trying to make a modal pop up when the user clicks on a button, which populates that modal with dynamic data related to the specific button the user clicked. If I have 4 buttons, and the user clicks on the first one, it opens all 4 modals and ends up displaying the very last modal. Why is this?

The React component that calls the modal:

```
const FindChallenges: React.FC = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  const [searchedChallenge, setSearchedChallenge] = useState<string>(); // what user searched.
  const [allChallenges, setAllChallenges] = useState<Array<any>>([]); // the challenges that match search.
  const [isOk, setIsOk] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [showModal2, setShowModal2] = useState(false);

  // Only works for web right now.
  // Will need to set up PORT forwarding for ios/android.
  const API_URL = "http://localhost:3001";

  useEffect(() => {
    // if (!isAuthenticated) return;
    fetch(API_URL + "/api/getChallenges", {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setAllChallenges(res)
        setIsOk(true);
        // let results = [];
        // for (let key in res) {
        //   results.push(res[key])
        // }
        // setAllChallenges(results);
        // setIsOk(true);

      })
  }, []);

  if (!isAuthenticated) return (<PageLock />);



  async function closeModal() {
    setShowModal(false);
    setShowModal2(false);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("FORM SUBMITTED");
    let obj = { "key1": "hi" };
    console.log(obj.key1)
  }




  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle className="ion-text-center">Find a Challenge</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        {/* <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">Find ChallengesTab</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader> */}
        <IonCard>
          {/* <IonItem>
            <IonLabel className="ion-text-center" id="profileLabel">Your Challenges</IonLabel>
          </IonItem> */}
          <IonCardContent id="ionCardContent">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <IonInput clear-input="true" id="search-challenge-input" value={searchedChallenge} placeholder="Enter Input" onIonChange={e => setSearchedChallenge(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
              <IonButton expand="block" type="submit" className="ion-margin-top">
                Search
              </IonButton>
            </form>
          </IonCardContent>
        </IonCard>
        <br></br>
        {console.log(allChallenges)}
        <IonCard>
          
          {isOk && allChallenges.map(challenge => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <IonModal  isOpen={showModal}>
                <ChallengeModal closeAction={closeModal}
                  title={challenge.name}
                  description={challenge.description} />
              </IonModal>
              <IonItem button className="ion-activated">
                <IonLabel onClick={(e) => 
                  setShowModal(true)}>{challenge.name}</IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
            </React.Fragment>

          ))}



        </IonCard>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default FindChallenges;
```

And here is the challenge modal

```
type ChallengeModalProp = {
  closeAction: Function;
  description: string;
  title: string;
}

export const Monsters = () => {
  const monsters = ["King Kong", "Godzilla", "Robert Redford"]
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
}

class ChallengeModal extends React.Component<ChallengeModalProp> {
  
  render() {
    return <>

      {console.log("HERE IS THE TITLE", this.props.title)}
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar >
          <IonTitle>{this.props.title}</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      
      <IonCard className='challenge-card'>
        <IonGrid className="image-grid">
          <IonRow className="image-row">
            <IonCol className="image-col">
            <div className="image-container">
              <IonImg className="challenge-image" src={PullUps} />
            </div>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              <IonCardHeader>
                <IonItem className="challenge-card-title">
                  <IonLabel id="profileLabel">{this.props.title}</IonLabel>
                  <IonButton id='profileBtn' fill="outline" slot="end"><span id="challenges" onClick={() => window.location.href='/dashboard/challenges'}>Accept Challenge</span></IonButton>
                </IonItem>
              </IonCardHeader>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              <IonCardContent>
              <IonList>
                <IonListHeader>
                  Description      
                </IonListHeader>
                <IonItem>
                  <IonLabel>
                    <IonText color="success">
                    <p>{this.props.description}.</p>
                    </IonText>
                  </IonLabel>
                </IonItem>
                </IonList>   
                <IonList>
                  <IonListHeader>
                    Challenge Type
                  </IonListHeader>
                  <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel>
                    <IonText color="success">
                      <p>Agility, Dexterity, Rhythm</p>
                      </IonText>
                    </IonLabel>
                  </IonItem>
                </IonList>
                <IonList>
                  <IonListHeader>
                    Goals     
                  </IonListHeader>
                  <IonAccordionGroup>
                    <IonAccordion value="Goals">
    
                      <IonItem slot="header">
                        <IonLabel>
                          <p>Goal1</p>
                        </IonLabel>
                      </IonItem>
                      <IonList slot="content">
                        <IonItem>
                          <IonLabel>
                            <p>Here is a description of goal1 if anyone is curious</p>
                          </IonLabel>
                        </IonItem>
                        </IonList>
                    </IonAccordion>

                    <IonAccordion>
                        <IonItem slot="header">
                        <IonLabel>
                          <p>Goal2</p>
                        </IonLabel>
                      </IonItem>
                      <IonList slot="content">
                        <IonItem>
                          <IonLabel>
                          <IonText color="success">
                            <p>Here is a description of goal2 if anyone is curious</p>
                            </IonText>
                          </IonLabel>
                        </IonItem>
                        </IonList>
                        
                      </IonAccordion>
                      </IonAccordionGroup>
                    </IonList>
                <IonList>
                  <IonListHeader>
                    Badges
                  </IonListHeader>
                  <IonItem>
                  <IonText color="success">
                    <IonLabel>
                    <IonText color="success">
                    <p>Gold Star</p>
                    </IonText>
                    </IonLabel>
                    <IonLabel>
                    <IonText color="success">
                    <p>Pink Ribbon</p>                
                    </IonText>
                    </IonLabel>
                    <IonLabel>
                    <IonText color="success">
                    <p>Red Balloon</p>
                    </IonText>
                    </IonLabel>
                  </IonText>
                  </IonItem>
                </IonList>
            </IonCardContent>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>

         
          </IonCard>




      <IonButton size="large" onClick={() => this.props.closeAction()}>
        Return
      </IonButton>

    </>
  };
};

export default ({closeAction, description, title}: { closeAction: Function, description: string, title: string }) => (
  <ChallengeModal closeAction={closeAction} description={description} title={title}>
  </ChallengeModal>
)
```

If I click on Yoga for example, the modal shows but displays the data for Cycling (the last button)
[UI image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpln9.png)

But if you look at the console, you can see that all 4 modals are opening but only the last one is being displayed. Does anyone know why??
[What comes up in the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVzDD.png)